# How to pass numpy.memmap array to np.cov function?

Tags: python, arrays, memory, numpy, out-of-memory

I want to pass numpy.memmap array to np.cov function, because I have MemoryError when working with ordinary numpy array.

something like

```
np.cov(data_c,rowvar=0,out=fcov)
```

here is my code snippet:

```
M= data.shape[0]
N= data.shape[1]
print data.shape
#get mean
mean= np.mean(data,axis=0)
print mean.shape
# print mean

#M x N
data_c= (data-mean) 
print data_c.shape
# print data_c

#N x N 
#calculate covariance matrix
# covData=np.cov(data_c,rowvar=0)   # must be memmaped array
fcov= np.memmap('cov.npy', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(N,N))
np.cov(data_c,rowvar=0,out=fcov)
print covData.shape
```

but the problem is np.cov has no out= parameter.

and when I use

```
fcov= np.cov(data_c,rowvar=0)
```

it seems inside np.cov is created temporary in memory copy of array or something.

I managed to replace np.cov function, but I don't understand why I must multiply by 2, because according to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22501/is-there-an-intuitive-interpretation-of-ata/22520#22520) it's just (A.T*A)/(n-1) and also it requires matrix transposition so it seems not very good solution.

```
def cov_mat(fmat):
    #if fmat centered then 2*(A.T*A)/(n-1) covariance matrix
    M= fmat.shape[0]
    N= fmat.shape[1]
    fcov= np.memmap('cov.npy', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(N,N))

    fmat_tr= np.memmap('A_tr.npy', dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(N,M))
    fmat_tr= fmat.T
    np.dot(fmat_tr,fmat,out=fcov)
    fcov= 2*fcov/(N-1)

    return fcov
```

Comment: @larsmans np.cov has no out= parameter.

Comment: @mrgloom I think the solution you posted in the question could go as an answer..., maybe doing `fcov *= 2/(N-1)`

Comment: @SaulloCastro can you explain why fcov *= 2/(N-1) is better? because if I use fcov= fcov*2/(N-1) it creates temp copy of memmaped array in memory?

Comment: @mrgloom I am not sure for a `memmap`, but for a "normal" array if you do `a = a*2` it will return a new array, but `a*=2` will multiply in place (you can check the id of the objects to prove that...